# TextField lose focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with TreeView and TextField. I wrapped those components in TreeViewContainer. I'd like to filter tree nodes by typing in TextField. The problem is when I select node and then try to filter Tree. TextField lose focus and first node that matched first character is selected (or sometimes log error).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
    at eval (TreeView.js:327)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at setFocusByFirstCharacter (TreeView.js:321)
    at printableCharacter (TreeItem.js:173)
    at handleKeyDown (TreeItem.js:262)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:336)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:385)
```

I wonder is it material-ui bug or am I doing something wrong?

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-platform-nptfh)

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063602/react-input-or-material-ui-textfield-not-working-inside-material-ui-treeview/59074693#59074693 and upvote it if it solves your problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell it's not working. I also try replace TextField with plain <input />  but problem still ocuur.

Comment: Can you save your sandbox? When I look at it, `TreeViewFilter.tsx` is empty.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Saved.

Comment: The `stopPropagation` needs to be in the `onKeyDown` not the `onChange` (e.g. `onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}`). See my modification of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-chebyshev-93cgi

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that :) Please open Drawer, try to expand Tree and click i.e. 'Tests'. Then focus on TextField and try to type: 'tests' to filter nodes that contain this word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeView` maintains the [focused node id within its state](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TreeView/TreeView.js#L44). When you re-render the tree with a different structure (e.g. removing the "Root" node), the `TreeItem`s are then being re-mounted rather than just re-rendered. `TreeItem` monitors [whether or not it should be focused](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TreeItem/TreeItem.js#L272) based on the `TreeView` context and if that changes it grabs focus. That focus logic is going to execute when a `TreeItem` mounts. Normally a `TreeItem` wouldn't grab focus on mount, but in your particular scenario since the `TreeView` is staying consistent and remembers the last focused `TreeItem`, but the items are all being re-mounted, it brings focus back to that `TreeItem`.

Another aspect of the problem is that the `TreeView` [remembers its nodes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TreeView/TreeView.js#L62). It [has logic to try to maintain this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TreeItem/TreeItem.js#L258), but it would seem that your scenario might be exposing a bug in that logic and the typing (once focus is back on the tree item) tries to look up the parent of a node that no longer exists (though I would need to dig into this quite a bit more with a simpler code sample to determine why the nodeMap isn't quite right and whether this is truly a bug).

You can fix both the focus shift and the out-of-date nodeMap info, by changing the key of the `TreeView` whenever you set a new tree after your search. This causes a re-mount of the `TreeView` so it no longer remembers the last focused node or the old node map.

Here's a modified version of the code from your sandbox (my changes are indicated by "Added by Ryan"):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TreeViewFilter from "./TreeViewFilter";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import { Folder } from "@material-ui/icons";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { amber } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import _ from "lodash";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400
  }
});

enum NodeType {
  FOLDER = 0,
  SCHEMA
}

type TreeNode = {
  name: string;
  type: NodeType;
  parent: string | null;
  childNodes: Array<TreeNode>;
};

export interface ITreeViewProps {
  tree: TreeNode;
  fetchItem?: () => void;
}

export default function TreeViewContainer(props: ITreeViewProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [tree, setTree] = useState(props.tree);
  // ** Added by Ryan ** New treeKey state
  const [treeKey, setTreeKey] = useState(1);

  function fetchItem(id: string) {
    // inicjacja pobierania schematu/listy alarmów/ raport/ wykresu
    console.log("Fetch  " + id);
  }

  function renderTree(tree: any) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree)) {
      return tree.map(item => buildTree(item));
    } else {
      return buildTree(tree);
    }
  }

  function buildTree(tree: TreeNode) {
    return (function recursive(currentNode: TreeNode) {
      if (currentNode.type === NodeType.FOLDER) {
        return (
          <TreeItem
            key={currentNode.name}
            nodeId={`${currentNode.type}${currentNode.name}`}
            label={
              <div>
                <Folder style={{ color: amber[500] }} />{" "}
                <span>{currentNode.name}</span>
              </div>
            }
          >
            {currentNode.childNodes.map(node => recursive(node))}
          </TreeItem>
        );
      }

      if (currentNode.type === NodeType.SCHEMA) {
        return (
          <TreeItem
            key={currentNode.name}
            nodeId={`${currentNode.type}${currentNode.name}`}
            onClick={() => {
              fetchItem(currentNode.name);
            }}
            label={currentNode.name + ".sh"}
          />
        );
      }

      return null;
    })(tree);
  }

  const searchTree = (tree: TreeNode, searchValue: string, callback: any) => {
    const searchRE = new RegExp(searchValue, "i");
    return (function recurse(currentNode: TreeNode) {
      for (let i = 0, length = currentNode.childNodes.length; i < length; i++) {
        recurse(currentNode.childNodes[i]);
      }
      if (currentNode.name.match(searchRE))
        callback({
          ...currentNode,
          childNodes: currentNode.childNodes.filter(node =>
            node.name.match(searchRE)
          )
        });
    })(tree);
  };

  const doSearch = (text: string) => {
    console.log("-------------------->>>>");

    setSearchValue(text);
    let newTree: any = [];
    searchTree(props.tree, text, function(node: any) {
      console.log(node);
      newTree.push(node);
    });

    console.log("===============");
    console.log(newTree); // usunąć item, którego parent jest tablicy
    function hasParentInCollection(item: TreeNode, index, arr) {
      if (arr.find((el: any) => el.name === item.parent)) return false;
      else return true;
    }
    newTree = newTree.filter(hasParentInCollection);
    //set new tree
    console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    console.log(newTree);
    setTree(newTree);
    // ** Added by Ryan ** Update treeKey state
    setTreeKey(oldKey => oldKey + 1);
  };

  const treeItems = renderTree(tree);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <TreeViewFilter doSearch={doSearch} value={searchValue} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* ** key={treeKey} added by Ryan */}
        <TreeView
          key={treeKey}
          className={classes.root}
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        >
          {treeItems}
        </TreeView>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit filtered TreeView]